# generate enum class from table with JOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, enums, jooq

I have the following table called YNM:

```
 id  name
 1   YES
 2   NO 
 3   MAYBE
```

and want JOOQ to generate the following java enum:

```java
public enum YNM {
   YES,NO,MAYBE;
}
```

I understand that support for this was dropped in JOOQ 3 for being overly complicated/anti-intuitive. Is there a way of achieving this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever find a full github example project to illustrate the concepts here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you could re-implement the removed feature on your side in a few steps:

#### 1. Implement the generator for that enum

You would need to override the `JavaGenerator` to implement the code generation for the translation of your master data (might be several tables) to enums. How that works is entirely up to you, e.g. you could have:

- Single column master data tables
- ID/VALUE mapping tables
- ID/VALUE/Comment mapping tables
- Other layouts

#### 2. Generate `ForcedType` configurations for those enums

Whenever such a master data table is referenced, you should re-wire the foreign key column to that enum using a `<forcedType/>` configuration. [This is best done by configuring your code generation programmatically](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-programmatic), as that would allow you to have more dynamic control over your jOOQ code generation configuration.

[This step is documented more in detail in Bill O'Neil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46433178/521799).

#### 3. Prevent the generation of the master data tables

In addition to the above, you should probably remove the master data tables themselves from your generated output. In your case, this should result in the configuration:

```
<excludes>YNM</excludes>
```

Or, if you have more than one master data table:

```
<excludes>YNM|OTHER_MASTER_DATA_TABLE|...</excludes>
```

Excluding these tables will prevent accessing them from jOOQ client code, as well as remove foreign key information in generated code, which might be confusing.

Comment: Can you please show a quick example how a enum-generator for the `YNM` table/rows would look like?
My generator `extends JavaGenerator` but not sure where to hook into. Two problems:
1) How to `SELECT` data from a table from *within my* generator? `JavaGenerator` has `private Database database` (to get a connection or `DSLContext` from) but is not available in a subclass. Should be `protected`?
2) Is hooking into `generateTable(...)` the way to go? However, in our case, as soon as you add `YNM` to `<excludes>` it wont get processed=>your point 3 causes point 1 to never be processed.

Comment: 1) Just hook into some generation logic, e.g. `generateSchema(SchemaDefinition)`. You'll get access to the database (and the JDBC connection) through the `SchemaDefinition` 2) Depends if you want to operate on a per-schema level or per-table level. Both are doable. 3) No that is unrelated.

Comment: Thanks Lukas, that were the hints I needed. I was able to implement my own generator and it is working great so far! I am using jOOQ since a couple of weeks and it is working great so far ;)

Comment: @LukasEder, I need to do exactly the same as this question. Can you please elaborate? I imported `<artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>` to have access to `org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator` and created a class extending from it. Should I duplicate same `generate(SchemaDefinition)` method and add my custom logic? And finally do I have to add my custom generator into the maven plugin config with `<name>...MyGenerator</name>`?

Comment: @FedericoPiazza: Please ask a new question with some details, e.g. what's not working, more details about your configuration, etc.

Comment: @LukasEder just created this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52171377/how-build-a-jooq-custom-generator

Answer (score 5):

I think you should be able to use an `EnumConverter`

```
public class YNMConverter extends EnumConverter<String, YNM > {

    public YNMConverter() {
        super(String.class, YNM.class);
    }
}
```

You will then need to add it to the codegen as a custom type and a forced type. Here is a programatic example

```
new CustomType()
.withName("YNM")
.withType(YNM.class.getName())
.withConverter(YNMConverter.class.getName());

new ForcedType()
.withTypes("varchar")
.withName("YNM")
.withExpression(".*ynm.*") // regex to match the column name
```

You need to add the forced type and custom type to the codegen. This is can be done in maven / xml or programatically

Comment: Is there a github example of how to do this in either maven/xml so that all the configs and everything are in one place? I've found lots of do this or that but it's only pieces and no complete solution to look at. If you know of an example it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I'm posting my answer since it might be useful for others.

I had to face the same needs and it was very difficult to achieve, so here you can find the code I implemented to generate enums from an `enums` schema.

The code was implemented in groovy, but for java it's very similar.

First and **very important**, I had to create a separate project for my enum generator since it will work as a dependency for the project that is going to use it. This is **needed** because the project generating the code must run the enum generator at compilation time, so the way to achieve this is by adding the enum generator as a dependency.

### Enum generator project dependency

```
package com.ctg.jooqgenerator.jooq

import org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator
import org.jooq.codegen.JavaWriter
import org.jooq.meta.Database
import org.jooq.meta.SchemaDefinition
import org.jooq.meta.TableDefinition
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

import java.sql.ResultSet

class EnumGenerator extends JavaGenerator {
    private static final String ENUMS_SCHEMA = "enums"

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EnumGenerator.class)

    @Override
    void generateSchema(SchemaDefinition schema) {
        // Apply custom logic only for `enums` schema. Others schema has regular generation
        if (schema.name != ENUMS_SCHEMA) {
            super.generateSchema(schema)
            return
        }

        log.info("Generating enums")
        log.info("----------------------------------------------------------")

        Database db = schema.database

        db.getTables(schema).each { TableDefinition table ->
            // Prepare enum name from snake_case to CamelCase
            String enumName = table.name.replaceAll('_([a-z])') { it[1].capitalize() }.capitalize()

            JavaWriter out = newJavaWriter(new File(getFile(schema).getParentFile(), "${enumName}.java"))
            log.info("Generating enum: {}.java [input={}, output={}]", enumName, table.name, enumName)

            printPackage(out, schema)

            out.println("public enum $enumName {")

            ResultSet rs = db.connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ${schema}.\"${table.name}\"").executeQuery()
            while (rs.next()) {
                String name = rs.getString('name'),
                       description = rs.getString('description'),
                       s = rs.isLast() ? ";" : ","

                // Generate enum entry
                out.tab(1).println("$name(\"$description\")$s")
            }

            out.println("""
            |    private final String description;
            |
            |    private $enumName(String description) {
            |        this.description = description;
            |    }
            |}
            """.stripMargin())

            closeJavaWriter(out)
        }

        log.info("----------------------------------------------------------")
        super.generateSchema(schema)
    }
}
```

### Database having enum tables

The tables that will be translated to enums look like this:

```sql
-- Table name `account_role` will be translated into `AccountRole`
CREATE TABLE enums.account_role (
    "name" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    description varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT account_role_name_key UNIQUE (name)
);

-- Table entries will be translated into enum entries
INSERT INTO enums.account_role ("name",description) VALUES 
('BILLING','Role for contact/address that will be a Billing contact/address'),
('PAYMENT','Role for contact/address that will be a Payment contact/address'),
('SERVICE','Role for contact/address that will be a Service contact/address'),
('SOLD_TO','Role for contact/address that will be a SoldTo contact/address')
;
```

This data definition will result in below autogenerated enum AccountRole.java:

```java
/*
 * This file is generated by jOOQ.
 */
package com.congerotechnology.ctgcommon.jooq.enums;

public enum AccountRole {
    BILLING("Role for contact/address that will be a Billing contact/address"),
    PAYMENT("Role for contact/address that will be a Payment contact/address"),
    SERVICE("Role for contact/address that will be a Service contact/address"),
    SOLD_TO("Role for contact/address that will be a SoldTo contact/address");

    private final String description;

    private AccountRole(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

---

### Main project

Then on the main project that is going to use this enum generator I have set the following maven code on `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependencies>
...
    <!-- JOOQ custom generator -->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.ctg</groupId>
       <artifactId>ctg-jooq-generator</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>

<build>
...
    <plugins>
        <!-- JOOQ code generation -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <jdbc>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://${env.DB_URL}</url>
                    <user>${env.DB_USER}</user>
                    <password>${env.DB_PASSWORD}</password>
                </jdbc>
                <generator>
                    <name>com.ctg.ctgjooqgenerator.jooq.EnumGenerator</name>

                    <database>
                        <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
                        <includes>.*</includes>
                        <excludes />
                        <dateAsTimestamp>true</dateAsTimestamp>
                        <inputSchema>enums</inputSchema>
                    </database>
                    <generate>
                        <deprecated>false</deprecated>
                        <instanceFields>true</instanceFields>
                    </generate>
                    <target>
                        <packageName>com.ctg.ctgcommon.jooq.enums</packageName>
                        <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq-postgres</directory>
                    </target>
                </generator>
            </configuration>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```