# How build a JOOQ custom generator?

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, code-generation, jooq

I have a specific Postgre schema that gathers all tables that defines types, like `Status(name, description)` where values could be `OPEN, Open item status`, `CLOSED, Closed item status`, etc.

We need to fetch all these tables and generate enums based on them to later use it within our app. So, these enums should look like:

```
enum Status {
    OPEN("Open item status"),
    CLOSED("Closed item status")
    ...
}
```

We decided to use JOOQ which looks pretty interesting, but we cannot find documentation/examples to create a custom generator that use default java generator behavior plus a custom enum generation extension.

Basing on this post [generate enum class from table with JOOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429671/generate-enum-class-from-table-with-jooq), it brought some ideas but still not clear what to do to achieve what the answer states.

Update: in order to have my custom generator to being picked by `jooq-codegen-maven` plugin I created a separate project and added its jar as a dependency of my parent project. I created a class `MyGenerator` and made it extend from `JavaGenerator`. In order to have this `org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator` I had to add below maven dependency (not coming in `spring-boot-starter-jooq`):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Once done this and inherited from JavaGenerator, according to the post answer I should hook into `generate(SchemaDefinition)` method, however this is not protected scope, so I think I'm missing something here.

Do you know or can you provide an example describing how to write this kind of code generator for enums? I need JOOQ to generate code as usual for a specific schema, but besides it I need to query another specific "enum" schema that only contains those "enum" tables.

Comment: Why are you adding the `jooq-codegen-maven` *plugin* as an ordinary dependency in your pom.xml, instead of a plugin?

Comment: @LukasEder I added it only to have available `JavaGenerator` for my custom generator. However, after reading your [post here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/5lfiz8yFDh0). I have to create a separate project for my custom generator. I can update the question to make it focus only in the enum generation only.

Comment: I see. For the record, the `JavaGenerator` is in the `jooq-codegen` artifact, which can be added as an ordinary dependency, rather than a transitive dependency through `jooq-codegen-maven`

Comment: @LukasEder I realized I had my question with no answered so I just provided the answer with details for people that might find it useful. This code worked very well for our needs, wanted to let you know since you can find it useful too for documentation purposes.

Comment: Very cool, thanks for doing this! That's almost a blog post :)

Comment: @LukasEder my pleasure. JOOQ is an amazing framework but not very popular, so I think this will help people that needs to use this feature. BTW, if you see any improvement feel free to suggest it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I'm posting my answer since it might be useful for others.

I had to face the same needs and it was very difficult to achieve, so here you can find the code I implemented to generate enums from an `enums` schema.

The code was implemented in groovy, but for java it's very similar.

First and **very important**, I had to create a separate project for my enum generator since it will work as a dependency for the project that is going to use it. This is **needed** because the project generating the code must run the enum generator at compilation time, so the way to achieve this is by adding the enum generator as a dependency.

### Enum generator project dependency

```
package com.ctg.jooqgenerator.jooq

import org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator
import org.jooq.codegen.JavaWriter
import org.jooq.meta.Database
import org.jooq.meta.SchemaDefinition
import org.jooq.meta.TableDefinition
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

import java.sql.ResultSet

class EnumGenerator extends JavaGenerator {
    private static final String ENUMS_SCHEMA = "enums"

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EnumGenerator.class)

    @Override
    void generateSchema(SchemaDefinition schema) {
        // Apply custom logic only for `enums` schema. Others schema has regular generation
        if (schema.name != ENUMS_SCHEMA) {
            super.generateSchema(schema)
            return
        }

        log.info("Generating enums")
        log.info("----------------------------------------------------------")

        Database db = schema.database

        db.getTables(schema).each { TableDefinition table ->
            // Prepare enum name from snake_case to CamelCase
            String enumName = table.name.replaceAll('_([a-z])') { it[1].capitalize() }.capitalize()

            JavaWriter out = newJavaWriter(new File(getFile(schema).getParentFile(), "${enumName}.java"))
            log.info("Generating enum: {}.java [input={}, output={}]", enumName, table.name, enumName)

            printPackage(out, schema)

            out.println("public enum $enumName {")

            ResultSet rs = db.connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ${schema}.\"${table.name}\"").executeQuery()
            while (rs.next()) {
                String name = rs.getString('name'),
                       description = rs.getString('description'),
                       s = rs.isLast() ? ";" : ","

                // Generate enum entry
                out.tab(1).println("$name(\"$description\")$s")
            }

            out.println("""
            |    private final String description;
            |
            |    private $enumName(String description) {
            |        this.description = description;
            |    }
            |}
            """.stripMargin())

            closeJavaWriter(out)
        }

        log.info("----------------------------------------------------------")
        super.generateSchema(schema)
    }
}
```

### Database having enum tables

The tables that will be translated to enums look like this:

```sql
-- Table name `account_role` will be translated into `AccountRole`
CREATE TABLE enums.account_role (
    "name" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    description varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT account_role_name_key UNIQUE (name)
);

-- Table entries will be translated into enum entries
INSERT INTO enums.account_role ("name",description) VALUES 
('BILLING','Role for contact/address that will be a Billing contact/address'),
('PAYMENT','Role for contact/address that will be a Payment contact/address'),
('SERVICE','Role for contact/address that will be a Service contact/address'),
('SOLD_TO','Role for contact/address that will be a SoldTo contact/address')
;
```

This data definition will result in below autogenerated enum AccountRole.java:

```java
/*
 * This file is generated by jOOQ.
 */
package com.congerotechnology.ctgcommon.jooq.enums;

public enum AccountRole {
    BILLING("Role for contact/address that will be a Billing contact/address"),
    PAYMENT("Role for contact/address that will be a Payment contact/address"),
    SERVICE("Role for contact/address that will be a Service contact/address"),
    SOLD_TO("Role for contact/address that will be a SoldTo contact/address");

    private final String description;

    private AccountRole(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

---

### Main project

Then on the main project that is going to use this enum generator I have set the following maven code on `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependencies>
...
    <!-- JOOQ custom generator -->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.ctg</groupId>
       <artifactId>ctg-jooq-generator</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
...
</dependencies>

<build>
...
    <plugins>
        <!-- JOOQ code generation -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <jdbc>
                    <driver>org.postgresql.Driver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:postgresql://${env.DB_URL}</url>
                    <user>${env.DB_USER}</user>
                    <password>${env.DB_PASSWORD}</password>
                </jdbc>
                <generator>
                    <name>com.ctg.ctgjooqgenerator.jooq.EnumGenerator</name>

                    <database>
                        <name>org.jooq.meta.postgres.PostgresDatabase</name>
                        <includes>.*</includes>
                        <excludes />
                        <dateAsTimestamp>true</dateAsTimestamp>
                        <inputSchema>enums</inputSchema>
                    </database>
                    <generate>
                        <deprecated>false</deprecated>
                        <instanceFields>true</instanceFields>
                    </generate>
                    <target>
                        <packageName>com.ctg.ctgcommon.jooq.enums</packageName>
                        <directory>target/generated-sources/jooq-postgres</directory>
                    </target>
                </generator>
            </configuration>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```